# Not able to make post request on Next js application deployed on AWS amplify

Tags: amazon-web-services, next.js, hosting, aws-amplify, webhooks

I created one next js application and setup one route in next js which handle post request coming form AI model which is working perfectly on local and on ngrok but when I deploy next js project on AWS amplify then I am not able to make post request on that next js deployed project and I tried from postman and in postman I am getting error 401 and I also update CORS policy in next js still facing issues.

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
    images:{
        domains:[
            "oaidalleapiprodscus.blob.core.windows.net"
        ]
    },
    async headers() {
        return [
            {
                // matching all API routes
                source: "/api/:path*",
                headers: [
                    { key: "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", value: "true" },
                    { key: "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", value: "*" }, // replace this your actual origin
                    { key: "Access-Control-Allow-Methods", value: "GET,DELETE,PATCH,POST,PUT" },
                    { key: "Access-Control-Allow-Headers", value: "X-CSRF-Token, X-Requested-With, Accept, Accept-Version, Content-Length, Content-MD5, Content-Type, Date, X-Api-Version" },
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
};

export default nextConfig;
```